# How to fix this react native error | error: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Xwx.png)

> error: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js) is not computed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error for a while and fixed it. any of you all having the same error just use the command below. it'll fix the error. ;)

**FIX :**

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

and then,

```
npx react-native start
```